# Finding a complex number when given its roots

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Given 3 complex numbers a, b, and c, does there always exist another number N where taking the cube root of N gives a, b, and c? If not, when is that possible? How do I find N? How does this extend to n complex numbers and nth root rather than 3?

I have a programming background much more than specifically a math background and I can only find sources talking about how to find the roots of a complex number rather that the reverse.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  If $a^3=N$ and $b^3=N$, then $(a/b)^3=1$, which constrains $a$ and $b$

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Explicit_expressions_in_low_degrees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$th roots of any complx number will always form $n$ evenly spaced points around a circle, centred at the origin - or in other words they all have the same modulus, and their arguments differ by multiples of $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$. That means that if you have three arbitrary complex numbers they will *not* all have the same cube.

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are not colinear (i.e. you can't draw a straight line through all three) then it *is* possible to draw a circle through them, but there's still no guarantee they will be evenly spaced, or even that the spacing between them will be rational multiples of $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, because of DeMoivre's theorem.  If $z_1, z_2, z_3 \in \mathbb C$ are distinct complex numbers, then we may express them in polar form as
$$z_k = \rho_k e^{i\theta_k}, \quad \rho_k = |z_k| > 0, \quad \theta_k = \arg(z_k), \quad k \in \{1,2,3\}.$$
Then the theorem states that
$$z_k^3 = \rho_k^3 e^{3\theta_k i},$$
and in particular, $$|z_k^3| = \rho_k^3.$$  For the requirement that $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are the cube roots of the same number, say $w$, this would imply that $z_k^3 = w$ for each such $k$.  But in general, there is no requirement that the magnitudes $\rho_k$ are equal; therefore, no such $w$ exists if $|z_k| \ne |z_j|$ for some $k \ne j$.
Another condition following from the theorem is that we also require $\arg(3z_k) \equiv \arg(3z_j) \pmod {2\pi}$; that is to say, the difference in arguments of distinct cube roots must be some integer multiple of $2\pi/3$.  Geometrically, these two conditions require $z_1, z_2, z_3$ to form an equilateral triangle centered at the origin.